# How to deactivate the license

Tags: license4j

I want to deactivate the any license which is already activated form License4j License Manager tool.

Lets say I deactivated the license from License4j License Manager tool. Now if I launch my application  should fail to start if my license is deactivate.

But I am not able to find any API which Activation Status will show me as License is deactivated.
I used Validation API which return License object and shows Activation Successful status and activation not required.

Answer (score 0):

When you deactivate the license using the manager tool, the activation is deleted on the server only, the activated license must be deleted in licensee's computer. Usually, the better approach is to call autoDeactivate method in API then delete the saved license file on the computer.

Comment: But how to know activation is deleted on the server ?. API respond Activation Successful in status. To call autoDeactivate method I should first check the status on sever (If deactivated) then only I can call autoDeactivate method and delete license from system. Which is my actual question.

Comment: You should call #LicenseValidator.checkOnlineAvailability after validating license, if it returns 0, it means license and/or activation was deleted on the license server; so delete the license file on user's computer.

Comment: I have checked that option, but I don't want to delete the license, only want to deactivate it.

Comment: checkOnlineAvailability method returns 0 if license and/or activation is deleted AND also when license is deactivated. So, you can safely use that and if get zero as the return value, remove the saved license file on users's computer.